# Jmeter - Constructing a URL in Jmeter with HTTP request

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I've got a URL with following format, I'm not quite sure how to generate this URL after "# " using an HTTP request using Jmeter, Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

${url}}/a/?case_type_category=cases#/case/list?cf={"case_type_category":"cases","case_manager":[2]}

Answer (score 0):

1. Just put everything into "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler and JMeter will parse it

   [image]
2. You don't need to construct URLs manually, they can be recorded using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

See [URL.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash) MDN documentation chapter for more details